# logrotate: How to configure and override defaults?

Tags: logrotate, globbing

I'm testing a logrotate configuration in `/tmp`. I'd like

1. to configure a default logrotate policy for `/tmp/*.log` files using my test configuration file `/tmp/logrotate.conf`
2. to handle a particular log file `/tmp/special.log` with a different policy configured in a separate logrotate config test file: `/tmp/logrotate.d/included`

But logrotate's response to my configuration is to say:

```
error: /tmp/logrotate.d/included:1 duplicate log entry for /tmp/special.log
```

What should I do differently?

Here's my `/tmp/logrotate.conf`

```
compress
missingok
notifempty
size 512k
copytruncate
rotate 2
su

# here's my attempt at applying the default policy to all /tmp/*.log
/tmp/*.log {}

# and here I intend to include any overrides
include /tmp/logrotate.d/included
```

And here's `/tmp/logrotate.d/included`

```
/tmp/special.log {
    size 300
}
```

Here's the debug output.

```
$ sudo logrotate -d ./logrotate.conf

reading config file ./logrotate.conf
including /tmp/logrotate.d/included
reading config file /tmp/logrotate.d/included
error: /tmp/logrotate.d/included:1 duplicate log entry for /tmp/special.log

Handling 2 logs

rotating pattern: /tmp/*.log  524288 bytes (2 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /tmp/normal.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /tmp/special.log
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /tmp/special.log  300 bytes (2 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.
```

1. The error surprises me because I thought according to the man page "Later config files may override the options given in earlier files, so the order in which the logrotate config files are listed is important."
2. Why does it say at the end when handling pattern `/tmp/special.log` that no logs were found? The file `/tmp/special.log` exists and is larger than 300 bytes.

Comment: Are your config files really in `/tmp/logrotate.d` - are you just testing from there rather than `/etc/logrotate.d`?  Can you post the command you used when you tested?

Comment: I'm just testing in `/tmp`. With the current working directory of `/tmp` I run this command: `sudo logrotate -d ./logrotate.conf` 
<next sentence:>
`normal.log` and `special.log` are owned by me.  `logrotate.conf` and `logrotated.d/included` are owned by root because when everything had been owned by me there was a permissions issue in changing some property while logrotate was running.

Comment: The permissions issue (when everything was owned by me and run non-sudo) was this: `switching euid to 0 and egid to 0 ...
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 0: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developers of `logrotate` have intentionally forbidden overlapping log-file definitions, so whilst more-specific rules are allowed to follow general rules in the configuration, log-file path overlaps still generate an error.  This is partly for the benefit of package-maintainers who include logrotate rules, and the users of those packages, so that overlaps become obvious and can be reported.

If the specific-rule and generic-rule log files *must* reside in the same directory (can you reconfigure to move them?), then you have to create and maintain an explicit exclusion to the generic rule for each overlapping path.  `logrotate.conf` doesn't provide for this explicitly, but if your `logrotate` runs in an environment with shell `extglob` glob-extensions enabled, the exclusion is possible.  You can check whether `extglob` is enabled by running `shopt extglob` in the same root environment your crontab logrotate will run, and it can be explicitly enabled (if required) with `shopt -s extglob`.

Once `extglob` is enabled, it allows for constructs such as:

```
/tmp/!(special).log {}
```

... which will prevent the overlap with your more-specific later rule, avoiding the error.